# Expression Calling "Any" using MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I'm trying to achieve the following code:

```
db.Invoices.Where(x => Dimensions.All(y => x.DimensionSet.Entries.Any(dim => (d.DimensionValue.DimensionCode + "_" + d.DimensionValue.Value) == y))
```

What I've tried:

```
/* Dimensions Logic
 * Copy the following logic: 
 * {&& Dimensions.All(y => x.DimensionSet.Entries.Any(d => (d.DimensionValue.DimensionCode + "_" + d.DimensionValue.Value) == y))}
 */

/* Get expression of the nested property Func<string, bool> to imitate the second argument of `Dimensions.All` */
Expression entriesExpression = Expression.Property(body, "Entries");

/* Get expression of the current Dimensions property */
Expression dimensionsExpression = Expression.Constant(Dimensions);

Type dimensionsAllType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string), typeof(bool));
Type innerAnyType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(DimensionSetEntry), typeof(bool));

/* Get the `All` method that may be used in LINQ2SQL
 * Making a generic method will guarantee that the given method
 * will match with the needed parameters.
 * Like it was a "real" linq call.
 */
MethodInfo methodAll =
    typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "All")
        .MakeGenericMethod(dimensionsAllType);

MethodInfo methodAny =
    typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Any")
        .MakeGenericMethod(innerAnyType);

MethodCallExpression call_Any = Expression.Call(
    null,
    methodAny,
    entriesExpression,
    Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Parameter(typeof(DimensionSetEntry), "y"))
);

MethodCallExpression call_All = Expression.Call(
    null,
    methodAll,
    dimensionsExpression,
    call_Any
);
```

Right now, I'm only struggling with the Expression Calls.

```
MethodCallExpression call_Any = Expression.Call(
        null,
        methodAny,
        entriesExpression,
        Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Parameter(typeof(DimensionSetEntry), "y"))
    );
```

Here I'm trying to call `Any` method of `Enumerable`. 
The expression `entriesExpression` represents `x.DimensionSet.Entries` (type: `ICollection<DimensionSetEntry>`)

and the next argument represents a constant `x => True` with the purpose of only testing the call for now, but here I'll need to insert `(d.DimensionValue.DimensionCode + "_" + d.DimensionValue.Value) == y`.

However, when calling this, the following error occurs:

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean
>   Any[Func`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Func`2[EmployeePortal.Models.DimensionSetEntry,System.Boolean]])'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Any()` has two overloads; one which only takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and one which also takes a lambda.

Your `methodAny` variable probably holds the first one.  You need to change that variable to find the overload with two parameters.